# Usage DataTrigger in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger, multidatatrigger

I have a `TextBox` control defined in XAML and I want to apply different background colors to the `TextBox` based on its IsReadOnly or IsEnabled properties. I used dataTriggers to actually switch between the colors as shown below:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And the TextBox is defined as shown below:

```
  <TextBox Name="sourceTextBox"  Margin="5,3,5,3" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
```

But the problem is, the colors are not being applied properly.

Is there any problem with the above approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need just need to add `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` to your bindings:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

There is still one problem however, I don't believe you will ever see a Red background because a TextBox with its IsEnabled property set to False has a built in background color into its control template that will take priority over your style's trigger's setter.

I think you'd have to redefine its control template to change the background color when the TextBox is disabled.

Answer (score 7):

You are unecessarily complicating things

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: 5 years on. But nice. Thank you.