# Textbox style trigger with "IsReadOnly" not working

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, triggers, textbox

I've made an application resource with a style which should be triggered if the textbox has the "IsReadOnly" property. Looks like this:

```
<Application.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                <Trigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger.Setters>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

However, the program doesn't react to this. It works when I use IsEnabled=True. However IsEnabled=False doesn't work either. So, question: Do the triggers only work if you check for "True"? And is IsReadOnly not supported at all? If so: How do I know which control properties are actually supported?

Comment: Did you set a background in the textbox, i.e., `<TextBox Background="White" />`? A setter in a trigger in a style can only override properties set by the style, not properties set directly in the element.

Comment: No, I didn't, Heinzi... The textbox looks like this:

<TextBox Text="{Binding Filename}" Height="24" Margin="85,43,12,0" Name="txtFile" TabIndex="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True" IsEnabled="False" />

Comment: Also, you will need another trigger with ``Value="False"`` (or ``Comparison="NotEqual"``) to reset the background to it's original state.

Answer (score 0):

See an answer for this problem by following the provided link:

[DataTrigger problem with textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868965/datatrigger-usage-problem-in-wpf)